# How to Return More than one JSON result

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have built a web service that connect to my Sql DB and returns requested amount of data via JSON.

If it returns a single record everything works great, however if it returns more than one the whole thing dies at the for loop.  Can anyone point me in the right direction to figure out why it is doing this.

```
NSString *urlString;
urlString = @"http://url.php";

NSData *jsonSource = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                      [NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:
                  jsonSource options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
for (NSDictionary *dataDict in jsonObjects) {
    NSString *idData = [dataDict objectForKey:@"ID"];
 dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                  idData, @"ID",
 Nil];
 [myObject addObject:dictionary];
```

I am trying to put this data into a Table View.

The JSON is:

```
[
    {
        "ID": "8",
        "APP_ID": "xx",
        "NAME": "xxx",
        "PRICING": "paid",
        "PRODUCT_ID": "xxx",
        "TITLE‌​": "xxx",
        "INFO": "xxx",
        "DATE": "2014-01-01 00:00:00",
        "AVAILABILITY": "published",
        "COVER": "xxxx",
        "URL": "xxxx",
        "ITUNES_SUMMARY‌​": "In this issue we interview Steve Jobs on all things Apple.",
        "ITUNES_COVERART_URL": "xxx",
        "ITUNES_PUBLISHED": "2012-11-01T00:00:00-07:0‌​0",
        "ITUNES_UPDATED": "2012-11-01T00:00:00-07:00"
    }
]
```

Here is the PHP that is generating the JSON output:

```
if($result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM ISSUES WHERE PRICING = 'free'")) { 
    $tempArray = array(); 
    while($row = $result->fetch_object()) { 
        $tempArray = $row; 
        array_push($json, $tempArray); 
        echo json_encode($json);
    }
 }
```

Comment: How does it die? Show the JSON for both cases.

Comment: It is not dying, it is waiting to be completed. Try using blocks to make an asynchronous download request

Comment: guessing here, but odds are NSJSONSerialization is returning a type that you're not expecting. @Wain is right, though. Would need to see the returned JSON.

Comment: here is the JSON for the single:  [{"ID":"8","APP_ID":"xx","NAME":"xxx","PRICING":"paid","PRODUCT_ID":"xxx","TITLE":"xxx","INFO":"xxx","DATE":"2014-01-01 00:00:00","AVAILABILITY":"published","COVER":"xxxx","URL":"xxxx","ITUNES_SUMMARY":"In this issue we interview Steve Jobs on all things Apple.","ITUNES_COVERART_URL":"xxx","ITUNES_PUBLISHED":"2012-11-01T00:00:00-07:00","ITUNES_UPDATED":"2012-11-01T00:00:00-07:00"}]

Comment: Can you POST the JSON?

Comment: the multiple just repeats more record from DB

Comment: Like I said as long as it is a single record it works fine.  But as soon as there are multiples it dies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that the response is valid JSON? Turn the JSON data into a string and print it to the console...

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonSource encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

... then check it in a JSON validator like [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.org) or [JSON Editor Online](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org).

You can also pass a pointer to an `NSError` object in the `NSJSONSerialization` method. Log this to the console too.

```
NSError *error;
id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonSource
                                                 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                   error:&error];
NSLog(@"error %@", error);
```

If there isn't any error message, then the final thing you should check is that the resulting `jsonObjects` variable is a type that you expect (I assume you're expecting an `NSArray`).

---

After seeing the PHP code, this should solve the problem:

```
if($result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM ISSUES WHERE PRICING = 'free'")) { 
    $tempArray = array(); 
    while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        array_push($row, $tempArray); 
    }
    echo json_encode($tempArray);
}
```

Comment: Ok, in the Error log I got a Garbage at end.

Comment: I also get a a no visible interface for NSString on the first line of code you gave.

Comment: Sorry about the "no visible interface" error, I tried to write the method from memory. Updated my answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "garbage"? garbage characters, or …?

Comment: That is just what is says.  Garbage at End.  Now here is what I figured out with your help.  At the JSON Editor Online if I give it the single return it works great and says its valid.  If I give it the multi it gives me an error right away. Parse error on line 1:
...01T00:00:00-07:00"}][{"ID":"8","APP_ID":
-----------------------^

Comment: here is the PHP code generating the JSON for me:  if($result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `ISSUES` WHERE `PRICING` = 'free'"))
  {
   $tempArray = array();
   while($row = $result->fetch_object())
   {
    $tempArray = $row;
    array_push($json, $tempArray);
    echo json_encode($json);    
   }
  }

Comment: I think I see what your problem is. It looks like instead of returning a single of array of assets, your web service is returning a bunch of arrays with 1 object each (and there's nothing separating them). That's invalid JSON, which is why `NSJSONSerialization` fails.

Comment: Looking into that now.  Thank you.  You have pointed me to the error of my ways.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your server just concatenates the JSON arrays

```
[ { "ID":"1", ... } ] [ { "ID":"2", ... } ] ...
```

This is invalid JSON, and `NSJSONSerialization` will stop after reading the first
JSON block, considering the rest as garbage.

The server must return an array with multiple dictionaries instead:

```
[ { "ID":"1", ... }, { "ID":"2", ... }, ... ]
```